# Android how get Context from specific class being in Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-context

I created Service class.
I can run it anywhere where I want, but I always need Context from MainMenuActivity.class.
I tried use getApplicationContext and getBaseContext but they show another class.

Thanks for answer

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }

}


public class MyService extends Service  {
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private MyLocationListener mylistener;
        public void onCreate() {
            handler.postDelayed(new runnable(), 10000);
    }

    private class runnable implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            mylistener = new MyLocationListener();
        }
    }
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }
}
```

[EDIT]
When I used getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext or MainActivity.this to getDefaultSharedPreferences, always it will be the same?

Comment: Why do you need specifically the Activity 's Context?

Comment: I need update value in SharedPreferences

Comment: Service is a context.

Comment: Yes. @MikeM. is correct. Why do you need Activity's Context when both Activity and Service are derived from Context itself.

Comment: Because later i would like execute this: `SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
prefs.getBoolean(string, value);`

Comment: You can do that with the Service Context.

Comment: In Service i created new Thread (Runnable) and then implements LocationListener, and in onLocationChanged i woudl like to execute SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution: 1**

In that case you have to use, `defaultSharedPreferences`. You can access the default shared preferences instance by:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context):
```

Example:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

This preference is shared across all your Activity and Service classes.

**Solution: 2**

You can create sharedPreference instance in your application class like:

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static SharedPreferences preferences;

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

}

And then you can manage your preferences as:

```
MyApplication.preferences.getString("key", "default");
```

Comment: It means when I use getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext or MainActivity.this to getDefaultSharedPreferences, it the same? of course for getDefaultSharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

add context parameter to your service class methods

```
public void myMethodInsideServiceClass(Context context){
   //bluh bluh
}
```

so that you can call from Activity Class like this

```
myMethodInsideServiceClass(this);
```

you can also try

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     public static myActivity;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         myActivity=this;
     }
}
```

so that you can use myActivity across the application
(i was not using editor to type code, sorry for syntax error)